# How to extract image url's stored in mysql database table

Tags: php

Need your help as I am stuck in extracting image url's stored in `mysql` database. Provided below is the data stored in `mysql` table. I want to extract the image url's and display in `loop`. I am unable to understand on how to start with and how to extract these url's from table. Request your support in getting this sorted out please.

```
["https:\/\/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/cdn.simplyrets.com\/properties\/trial\/home4.jpg","https:\/\/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/cdn.simplyrets.com\/properties\/trial\/home-inside-4.jpg"]
```

Comment: ["https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home4.jpg","https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home-inside-4.jpg"] this data is in single column or multiple column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first fetch the row, as it will return a string containing all images.
suppose after you fetching value it will be something like this

```
$images = '["https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home4.jpg","https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home-inside-4.jpg"] ';
```

run

```
$images = substr($images, 0, -1); //remove last "]" from string
$images = substr($images, 1); //remove first "[" from string

$new_images = explode(",", $images); // this will explode images from string to array
```

now use loop

```
for($i=0; $i<count($new_images); $i++){
echo $new_images[$i]; 
}
```

Comment: Great Tariq! Thanks for instantanious reply. I will check with this and will revert back shortly. Thanks a Ton :-) !

Comment: please check  substr($images, 1); again i hv edited .. and also during echo in loop the image name will print with quotes "" , if you want to remove them use str_replce or sub_str again ..

Comment: Hi Tarq! Now i have a new issue. I am also having forward shash "\" in the gien url. Can you please help on how to get the same removed as well?

Comment: run this in loop  str_replace("\\",  "", $new_images[$i]); replce \ to null ""

Comment: Thanks Tariq! It worked fine. Now i got this output from file: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home4.jpghttps://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home-inside-4.jpg In this output i have 2 image url's. Now i want to display them. Please suggest how i can do this as there is no seperator found for these 2 url's

Comment: Thanks Tariq!. I got this worked now. Thanbks a Ton for your wonderful support.

Comment: this shouldn't be output.. please try use echo "<br>", after echo $new_img.. in loop .. and see what its showing.. the images should display sepratly..

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($iamgeArray);$i++)
{
echo $imageArray[$i];
}
```

Comment: Hi Sujal! Thanks for your instant response. But then i am looking for ways to extract the url's first from table as these images are not stored in database folder. but are stored in table. SO 1st i need to extract them and then i can loop them. Also please understand that there are several texts as well in the given table hence we need to locate and extract the url's first.

Comment: in table url store in array for in single table field

Comment: Please explain in details. I am unable to understand. Provided below is the data in table. please explain on how to extract the url's


 ["https:\/\/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/cdn.simplyrets.com\/properties\/trial\/home4.jpg","https:\/\/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/cdn.simplyrets.com\/properties\/trial\/home-inside-4.jpg"]

Answer (score 0):

Remove brackets from string using str_replace

```
$string = '["https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home4.jpg","https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cdn.simplyrets.com/properties/trial/home-inside-4.jpg"] ';
$string = str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$string);
```

Then explode it with , separator

```
   $arr= explode(',',$string);
```

finally loop it through array

```
foreach($arr as value)
{
  echo $value;
}
```